# Modify the color of series in highcharts-ng

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

I have an AngularJS application in which I am using highcharts-ng version 0.0.86. I am trying to implement a feature where the user will set the color of the series after the chart is generated. I am trying to update the series color(from the browser console) using the following code:

```
$("#myHighChart").highcharts().series[0].color='#ffffff'
$("#myHighChart").highcharts().redraw()
```

Calling the redraw() method does not update the color of the series.

What is the correct way of updating the color of series?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the series color by following code

```
$(".chartColumn").highcharts().series[0].userOptions.color='#FF0000'
$(".chartColumn").highcharts().series[0].update()
```

This will update the color of the series as well as the data point.